# List devices/computers that have been authorized for ADB USB Debugging

Tags: adb, usb-debugging, shell

I want to know which devices I have already connected to my computer with my ADB or know which computers I have connected to my phone previously. Either way works for me.

`adb devices -l` does not show anything important, because it only displays currently attached.

I would prefer a way without root (on phone), but will accept any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see which devices were authorized by you on your phone to interact with it through  adb. **You would need root access though.**

Go into the directory `/data/misc/adb/`. There would be two files:

- adb_keys
- adb_temp_keys.xml

`adb_keys` shows the public key of the other device followed by its user@machine name format. The user@machine should tell you which machines or the users from other device tried to interact with your device over adb.

```
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 root@slackware.aes
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 neon@neon
```

`adb_temp_keys.xml` also has the same information as in adb_keys file except that it is formatted in XML and also shows last connection time (in UNIX Epoch format).

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<adbKey key="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 neon@neon" lastConnection="1616486869211" />
<adbKey key="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 root@slackware.aes" lastConnection="1616487035512" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does it work even when the user has pressed the "Revoke usb debugging authorizations" or something like that? Sorry for late reply by the way.

Comment: I have not tried this, but I don't think it should have a record of those devices.

Comment: Oh. Well anyway I am going to mark this as an answer because atleast it works given that the user hasn't pressed the button. Thank you for the generous help.